# How to setup weechat to connect with facebook google talk and skype?

Tags: irc

I'm looking for solution to tight all my communication channels I'm currently using: FB, GTalk and Skype into the terminal based chat client like weechat.

It looks like FB and GTalk use XMPP, but it's really hard to setup suggested weechat plugin jabber.py http://www.weechat.org/scripts/stable/tag/xmpp/

How to deal with weechat + XMPP problem. And how to setup skype chat.

Answer (score 2):

For instant messaging via IRC, two solutions are connecting to a [bitlbee](http://www.bitlbee.org/main.php/news.r.html) or [minbif](https://symlink.me/projects/minbif/wiki/) server. I don't believe skype is possible via either though.